# How to log @Query in PagingAndSortingRepository?

Tags: spring, hibernate, logging, spring-boot, spring-data

Is there a way to log some custom **@Query method**?

Here is example of my code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM transfer WHERE char_length(internal_id) = 5 " +
        "AND internal_id REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND project_id = :projectId order by created_at desc limit 1", nativeQuery = true)
Transfer findLastWithDefaultOurIdForProject(@Param("projectId") String projectId);
```

It's written in *interface*  that extends *spring-data* **PagingAndSortingRepository**.

I have tried to log it with adding these lines in property file:
`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE`

but I only get queries without real values passed from my service to repository interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this configuration:

`application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.database=h2
```

Add `logback.xml` file under `src/main/resources` to configure **Hibernate** to show parameters passed to the SQL Query:

`logback.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false" >
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate.type" additivity="false" >
        <level value="TRACE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

</configuration>
```

You can find the working [Demo Project](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/SpringDataLog) in my GitHub repository.

Comment: but is there a way to show real values passed to queries?

Comment: @Raca See the log. This does show the real values paased to the sql query but in the lines below. It shows question mark in the query and real value passed is displayed in lines below. You can check the demo project and you'd see the real values after sql query.

Comment: thanks, it is true:) log is too much long but all infos are there :)

Comment: Yes, unfortunately real values don't show up in sql query directly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your application properties. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels

You have the wrong prefix on the properties.

`logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE`

Comment: i changed properties... but is there a way to show real values passed to queries?