# Finding all entries where a collection field contains any of the given items

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have a Spring Boot application that contains an entity like this (some fields stripped for compactness):

```java
@Entity
public class Message extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Tag.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Tag> tags;
    // getter and setter for tags here
}
```

`Tag` is just a simple entity with a name field.

---

Now, I have another `Set<Tag>` in my code obtained from the user. I want to find all `Message`s that have any of the tags in this set. For example, if we have the following messages:

```
ID    TAGS
1     1, 2, 3
2     2, 5, 7
3     2, 4, 7
```

Then the query should, given the set `[3, 4]` return messages 1 and 3.

---

I tried writing this repository:

```java
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    List<Message> findByTags(Set<Tag> tag);
}
```

I enabled [query logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535232/how-to-log-query-in-pagingandsortingrepository) and my code produced a query, which I've cleaned up a bit here. The query produces no results in the cases I tried, and I have no idea what the `scalar = array` comparison is doing.

```sql
SELECT message.id AS id FROM message
LEFT OUTER JOIN message_tags ON message.id = message_tags.message_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tag ON message_tags.tags_id = tag.id
WHERE tag.id = (1,2,3,4,5) -- this is the input set
```

---

As suggested by @AliDehghani I tried writing the method as `findByTagsIn(Set<Tag> tag)`. This replaced the last `=` with `in` in the query.

I got results, but there was another problem: the results were repeated for each matching tag as one might guess from the query. For example, searching for `[2, 7]` with the example messages above would return message 1, message 2 twice and message 3 twice.

As far as I know adding some kind of `GROUP BY` clause might help here.

---

The [predefined query method keywords](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#d0e1599) don't seem to have any features related to this either, so I think I have to write my own using `@Query` or something else.

I can't seem to figure out a query that would work either, and I'm not very experienced in H2 so I don't really want to guess how one might work either.

I don't want to write a method that find all messages with a single tag, call it for each tag and combine the results, since that would be ugly and, given a lot of tags as input, very slow. How should I write my query method?

Comment: Did you try `findByOpinionsIn(Set<Tag> tags)`?

Comment: @AliDehghani That gets me results, but they are repeated for each matching tag.

Comment: What do you mean? You get some messages more than once?

Comment: @AliDehghani I updated the question. Basically if a message matches more than one tag in the parameter list it returns the message again for each tag.

Comment: `findDistinctByOpinionsIn(Set<Tag> tags)`?

Comment: @AliDehghani That worked. Post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> List findByTags(Set tag);

As you can see from the query log, this query method will only find messages that are tagged with all tags in the given `tag` parameter, which is not what you want.

In order to find messages that are tagged with either of those tags, you can use the following query method:

```
List<Message> findByTagsIn(Set<Tag> tag);
```

> I got results, but there was another problem: the results were
>   repeated for each matching tag as one might guess from the query.

In order to get rid of those repeated messages, you can fetch only distinct values:

```
List<Message> findDistinctByTagsIn(Set<Tag> tag);
```