# Finding all entries where a collection field contains ALL of the given items

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

So my question is fairly similar to the one in [Finding all entries where a collection field contains any of the given items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910464/finding-all-entries-where-a-collection-field-contains-any-of-the-given-items)

Except that rather than:

```
List<Message> findDistinctByTagsIn(Set<Tag> tag);
```

returning all Messages with ANY of the given tags, I'd like to know the syntax for a query that will only return messages that contain ALL of the given tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `ALL`, you can see how the sql `ALL` clause works on internet. You can then define it as a custom query in the `@Query` annotation, which will let you define your own sql such as below

```
@Query( "select t from Tags t where tag_ids =  all :ids" )
List<Message> findAllDistinctByTags(@Param("ids") Set<Tag> tag);
```