# Spring JPA add pagination to @ManyToMany

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, many-to-many

In my current project, I am using JPA and Hibernate to handle my database layer.

One of my entities has a Many-To-Many relation to itself, which works great using the `@ManyToMany` and the `@JoinTable` annotations.

My problem is that I am asked to add a pagination support to the entity. I have searched online for a solution but the closest thing I have found to a solution works on a different use case, where the relation is between 2 entities (and not an entity to itself).

This is the important parts from the entity's class:

```
package iob.data;

import iob.data.primarykeys.InstancePrimaryKey;
import iob.logic.exceptions.instance.InvalidBindingOperationException;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;


@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "INSTANCES")
@IdClass(InstancePrimaryKey.class)
public class InstanceEntity {
    //<editor-fold desc="Primary key">
    @Id
    // The index would be generated from a sequence named "INSTANCES_SEQUENCE"
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "INSTANCES_SEQUENCE")
    // Here we create that sequence, and define it to be updated every insertion (allocationSize = 1).
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "INSTANCES_SEQUENCE", sequenceName = "INSTANCES_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;
    @Id
    @NonNull
    private String domain;
    //</editor-fold>

    //<editor-fold desc="Many to Many relation">
    // Define a new table that would store the references
    @JoinTable(name = "INSTANCES_TO_INSTANCES",
            // The main columns for this attribute are the parent's primary key which is constructed from domain and id
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_DOMAIN", referencedColumnName = "domain")},

            // The referenced columns for this attribute are the child's primary key which is also constructed from domain and id
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                    @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_DOMAIN", referencedColumnName = "domain")})
    // Declare the parent's side of the relation
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<InstanceEntity> parentInstances = new HashSet<>();

    // Declare the children's size of the relation, and define that it is related to the parentInstances
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "parentInstances", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<InstanceEntity> childInstances = new HashSet<>();
    //</editor-fold>

    public void addParent(InstanceEntity parent) {
        if (this.equals(parent))
            throw new InvalidBindingOperationException("Cannot assign parent to himself");
        parentInstances.add(parent);
    }

    public void addChild(InstanceEntity child) {
        if (this.equals(child))
            throw new InvalidBindingOperationException("Cannot assign child to himself");
        childInstances.add(child);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, domain);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        InstanceEntity entity = (InstanceEntity) o;
        return id == entity.id && domain.equals(entity.domain);
    }
}
```

So far I tried (probably naively) write the getter for `parentInstance` and pass it a `Pagable` object (because it works on `derived-queries`, so worth a shot ) but obviously it did nothing.

The only solution I can think of is removing the relation, and creating it manually (create the table using another entity and add a new `PagingAndSortingRepository` that would retrieve the relevant instances and then convert them to `InstanceEntity` in the service).

So, how can I add a pagination support for `parentInstances` and `childInstances`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in some [unexpected post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911897/9977758). It is not about pagination, but it still solved my problem.

So the solution in my case was to add the following function to my `PagingAndSortingRepository` interface:

```
Page<InstanceEntity> findDistinctByParentInstancesIn(@Param("parent_instances") Set<InstanceEntity> parentInstances, Pageable pageable);
```

And then calling it is:

```
InstanceEntity ie = new InstanceEntity();
ie.setDomain(parentDomain);
ie.setId(Long.parseLong(parentId));
instancesDao.findDistinctByParentInstancesIn(Collections.singleton(ie), PageRequest.of(page, size));
```

To be honest, I'm not sure how/why it works. IntelliJ IDEA gives me an error in the repository interface `Expected parameter types: Collection<Set<InstanceEntity>>`.

So if someone has an explanation, I would be glad to hear it.